# checkbox.checked always returning true inside onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, checkbox, onclick

I cannoot figure out this seemingly simple problem. I have a checkbox and an onclick associated with it inside my JSP page. When i click the checkbox I need to check inside this onclick function whether it is checked or unchecked to know what action to take. However, it is always checked! I do not know why. Its almost like the click action completes and marks it checked before it gets to this function. However, if i do a simple HTML example page it works just fine and returns the correct value for .checked. 
I have tried removing "this" and just calling the checkbox by ID from onclick with the same results
Here is the setup:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" onclick="selectEntireRange(this);"/> Select ALL Ranges</label>
```

Here is the JS:

```
function selectEntireRange(checkElement)
{
  // if checked - remove check and display table rows normally
  if(checkElement.checked)
  {
    //ALWAYS EXECUTES HERE!
    checkElement.checked = false;
    greyoutAllTableRows(false);
  }
  // if unchecked - mark 'checked' and grey out all table rows
  else
  {
    checkElement.checked = true;
    setAllCheckBoxes(false);
    var selectedRangeField = document.getElementById('effRange');
    selectedRangeField.value = '';
    greyoutAllTableRows(true);
  }
}
```

any help would be awesome! Thanks!

P.S. I cannot use jQuery for this!

Comment: Did you try the `onchange` event instead

Comment: Hi, yes, but with IE onchange only triggers when the checkbox loses focus, which is not what i want.

Comment: Try the first answer in this post, I think it will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459021/how-to-apply-checkbox-with-functions-in-javascript

Comment: A workaround would be to have a hidden input element that contains 1 when checked and 0 when not. You just have to make sure it toggles every time `selectEntireRange` is called.

Comment: You know, i think i might just stick with this workaround for now! Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
onclick="selectEntireRange(this.checked)"
```

then change function to ask if its true or false or 0 or 1 or what ever the default check values are. not sure.

Comment: clever approach! Unfortunately, always checked as well :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because of your setting of `checkElement.checked = false;` inside if/else block. Comment\Remove that line out and it will work. Since on click you are setting it back to false, the checkbox does not go into the checked status and every time user clicks on it,it gets unchecked because of `checkElement.checked = false;` line.

Comment: But it is incorrectly reporting the status of "checked" even before that line. Anyways, i just ran it again with that line removed ... still wrong. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Let me know the browser and the version if you do not find it working on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkanand4/RN68K/).